# Send all emails from a user's Courier IMAP account

Tags: email, postfix, imap, courier

Is there any way of resending all the mails from a user's `cur` folder with the current emails on the server? The imap service is done by Courier and the smtp by `Postfix`

Path `/var/vmail/DOMAI.com/USER/`

Answer (score 4):

Just write a little script to loop over all the e-mails in the folder and pipe them through `sendmail`.  If necessary, you can mangle the content of the e-mails as required (say, to strip headers or change the To: address) using `formail` (part of `procmail`).

Comment: The user has been wombled